# Can you use the USB Drive?

Tags: lacuna-passage

In [Lacuna Passage](https://lacunapassage.com/), one of the items that I have found exploring is a USB Drive. It could be dissected for parts, but I can't help but think that there is something useful on it. Can I actually do something useful with the USB, or should I take it apart?